# Kafka consuming a single topic from multi node

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer application running on two different devices trying to consume the same topic `topic x` with each one having its own broker. The two brokers connected to the same zookeeper.

[image]

Is this architecture possible with Kafka? am I able to consume the same topic with different brokers on different devices? I am trying to implement this but I get this error `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kafka, brokers are not consuming topics. Brokers work together to form a cluster that, as a whole, hosts and serves potentially multiple topics while offering replication and high availability. The brokers receive and store messages sent by the producers to each particular topic, and allow consumers to consume from those topics with various semantics (see "consumer groups").

I'm not sure what devices you are dealing with, but a typical setup is to have a cluster of Kafka brokers (backed by a ZooKeeper cluster), and have your applications, producers and consumers, connect to this Kafka cluster by giving them the list of the brokers' hostnames.

Depending on your needs, number of topics, number of producer/consumers, etc, you can size your ZooKeeper and Kafka clusters. A good start is 3 of each, so you can at least have some amount of high availability by being able to lose one node without data loss. For development or just playing around, a single-broker Kafka cluster backed by a single-node ZooKeeper cluster will work just fine though.

Finally, if you have multiple devices consuming from that same topic, you have to decide if you want them to receive the same messages, or if you want them to share the load. If the first case, you'll need to make sure they are consuming as two distinct consumer groups. For the latter, you need to make sure they are in the same consumer group so they don't each receive the same messages.

To learn more, check out Kafka's [Introduction](http://kafka.apache.org/intro) document.

Comment: Thanks,
I am build self project, and i want to run only one ZK and on every device run his broker, i want to consume the same topic, i can do that?

Comment: No. You can run one ZK node and one Kafka broker (potentially on the same machine), and then have your devices connect to that broker to consume the topic. But that's obviously not a HA system.